# What is the nginx equivalent of `apachectl -S`?

Tags: nginx

With Apache `apachectl -S` lists all enabled sites by IP address and port, including the vhost file.

eg.

```
$ sudo apachectl -S
#VirtualHost configuration:
172.31.111.200:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server foo.bananas.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.bananas.co.uk:1)
         port 80 namevhost foo.bananas.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.bananas.co.uk:1)
172.31.111.200:443     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server foo.bananas.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.bananas.co.uk:9)
         port 443 namevhost foo.bananas.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.bananas.co.uk:9)
```

How do I get this information with nginx?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45485967/1460978

Comment: @QIS That's useful, thanks, but a bit more than I would like.